# Opera HTML5 video readyState == 2 instead of equaling 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, readystate

On the 4 other main browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari), the readyState goes to 4 and my code executes just fine.  On Opera however readyState only reaches 2 and never reaches 4.

Code:

```
var createSeekslider = function() {
    if($atVideo[0].readyState == 4) {
        var videoDuration = $atVideo[0].duration;
        $seekSlider = $('.videoSeekslider').slider({
            orientation:'horizontal',
            range:'min',
            min:0,
            max:videoDuration,
            value:0,
            step:0.01,
            animate:true,

            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $atVideo[0].currentTime = ui.value;
            }
        }); //End of (seekslider).slider function       
        } else {
            setTimeout(createSeekslider, 150);
        }
    }
createSeekslider();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to capture the moment when `readyState` becomes equal to 4, I'd recommend slightly different strategy - handling `canplaythrough` event:

```
$atVideo[0].addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
  // actually, `$atVideo[0].oncanplaythrough = function()` should do fine too
  $seekSlider = $('.videoSeekslider').slider({
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    range: 'min',
    min: 0,
    max: this.duration,
    value: 0,
    step: 0.01,
    animate: true,
    slide: (function(event, ui) {
      this.currentTime = ui.value;
    }).bind(this)
  });
});
```

I suspect your problem here is the same as described in [**this issue**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73609): in short, Opera sets `readyState` to 4 (`HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`) right after it starts loading the video, then switches it to 2 (`HAVE_CURRENT_DATA`) when some substantial part of it is loaded - which is too fast for the check scheduled by `setTimeout` to catch.

Comment: That $atVideo[0].addEventListener('canplaythrough', function()) was exactly what I needed! Works like a charm now! Thank you!